# Why is the word "тот" used in this sentence and why is it in the dative case?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, выбор-слова, падежи, склонение

Here's the text from my book:

-У вас есть стихи Лермонтова?
-Нет, к сожалению, стихи Лермонтова проданы.
-Но ведь они были несколько дней тому назад!
-Да, но всё уже продано.

I don't understand the usage of "тому" here. What is its effect on this sentence, and what's the difference between this sentence and simply saying "Но ведь они были несколько дней назад!"?

Comment: Long story short, "тот" and "тому (назад)" shouldn't be thought as the same word here: one is a general-purpose pronoun and another is a part of a set phrase. To better grasp the meaning and make things more fun, I'd suggest a non-canonical translation of "100 лет тому вперед" (a popular book title by Kir Bulychev) as a "100 years back to the future". What I mean is that you can actually think of those words ("тому назад") as "back then" or "back there".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Тому́ наза́д** is a set expression meaning "ago":

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/тому_назад](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4)

**Назад** is a shorter and more modern way of the saying the same.

Note that the time span is in the Accusative:

- **неделю** (тому) назад

which in most cases coincides with the Nominative:

- **год** назад
- **три дня** назад